# como puedo importar un resultado de un modulo?

Tags: python, modulos

introduje un modulo a un programa pero cuando intento usar una de las variables del modulo, el programa me dice que no encuentra este esta variable. Entonces mi pregunta es: como hago para que me reconozca la variable?
les voy a dejar como se ve el programa y el modulo, por si alguno ve un error.

gracias de ante mano a todos los que intenten ayudarme, se los agradezco mucho  :)

```
print("****si no coloca una figura valida, solamente precione enter despues del: desea calcular otra 
figura?****")
figura_deseada=input("escriba la figura que desea calcular: ") 
import modulocirculo
if figura_deseada=="circulo" or figura_deseada=="Circulo":
    print("usted escogio el circulo")
    print("para calcular el area del circulo unicamente digite el radio")
    print("y para calcular la circunferencia solo digite el diametro")
    radio=input("escriba el radio del circulo: ")
    pi=3.14
    diametro=input("escriba el diametro del circulo: ")
    print("el area del circulo es: ", resultado_area_circulo)
    print("la circunferencia del circulo es: ", resultado_circunferencia_circulo)
    calculo_circulo(radio, pi, diametro)
```

y ahora les voy a mostrar el modulo

```
def calculo_circulo(radio, pi, diametro ):
if radio=="":
    radio=None
else:
    radio= float(radio)

pi=3.14

if diametro=="":
    diametro=None
else:
    diametro= float(diametro)


if radio and pi and not diametro:
    resultado_area_circulo= pi * (radio * radio) 
    print(resultado_area_circulo)
elif diametro and pi and not radio:
    resultado_circunferencia_circulo= pi * diametro
    print(resultado_circunferencia_circulo)
```

Comment: Debes usar el nombre del módulo como "prefijo" de los símbolos (variables o funciones) que se definan en ese módulo. Es decir, desde el programa principal deberías hacer `modulocirculo.calculo_circulo()` para invocar a la función que hay dentro del módulo. A lo que no podrás acceder es a las variables que definas dentro de esa función. Por ello la función debería retornar esos valores para que el programa principal pueda usarlos (si ese es tu propósito)

Comment: ok gracias pero como lo retorno?, mi intencion es que me imprima el resultado de una de las variables que esta dentro del modulo, pero no se como hacer para que encuentre esa variable y la imprima, solamente me sale un error y me dice que no encuentra la variable que es: resultado_area_circulo

Comment: esa variable pertenece a la función y no puedes verla desde fuera. No es ya que esté en otro módulo, es que está en otra función. La solución como digo es retornarla y en el programa principal guardar ese valor retornado en otra variable. He escrito una respuesta que espero te lo aclare.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes dos problemas en la pregunta:

- De sintaxis. Para acceder a símbolos que han sido definidos en un módulo debes anteponer el nombre del módulo separado por punto: `modulo.simbolo`. Eso sirve para acceder por ejemplo a tu función, que debería ser por tanto `modulocirculo.calculo_circulo()`.

  Una forma de evitar esto es cambiar el `import` para que diga `from modulocirculo import calculo_circulo`. En ese caso estás trayendo al espacio de nombres global el nombre de esa función, por lo que podrías llamarla sin poner el nombre del módulo delante.
- De concepto. Las funciones normalmente hacen algún tipo de cálculo y **retornan** el resultado, en lugar de imprimirlo. De ese modo el programa que use la función puede obtener dicho resultado en otra variable propia que puede usar si quiere para otras cosas (como por ejemplo como parte de otros cálculos).

  Aún si lo que quieres es imprimir el resultado, no debería ser la función quien lo imprima. La función debe limitarse a calcular el resultado *y retornarlo*, y que sea el programa principal quien imprima ese valor.

¿Cómo se retorna un resultado desde una función? Simplemente escribiendo `return resultado`. Aunque en tu caso la función computa *dos* resultados, lo que no es muy habitual y sería más correcto tener dos funciones separadas, cada una especializada en una sola operación. Es lo que se llama *principio de responsabilidad única* (cada función debe hacer una sola cosa, bien definida).

Tener una sola finalidad bien definida ayuda también a poner un buen nombre a la función. `calculo_circulo` no es muy descriptivo ¿qué cálculo hace exactamente? Sería mejor decir `calculo_area_circulo()` o `calculo_circunferencia_circulo()`. Al buscar un nombre apropiado es fácil darse cuenta de si la función tiene o no una única responsabilidad clara. Tu función debería llamarse `calculo_area_y_circunferencia_circulo()`. El nombre es ya un indicador de que mejor serían dos funciones.

Ya de paso podemos mejorar un poco más estas funciones en la forma siguiente:

- ¿Por qué pasarles pi como parámetro? Los parámetros son valores que *pueden variar* de una ejecución a otra. Pi en cambio siempre tiene el mismo valor. No tiene sentido por tanto pasarlo como parámetro.
- ¿Por qué pasarle radio y diámetro si en realidad sólo necesita uno de los dos? Mejor pasarle sólo el que vaya a necesitar.
- ¿Por qué contemplar el caso en que radio o diámetro sean ""? No tiene sentido que alguien llame a estas funciones y les pase "" como valor del radio. Si alguien lo hace se merece un error, que es lo que ocurrirá si no intentamos comprobar el parámetro.

Quedarían entonces así:

```
# modulocirculo.py

from math import pi # Obtenemos el valor de pi de la biblioteca matemática
                    # en vez de asignarle 3.14 que además es bastante inexacto

def calcula_area_circulo(radio):
   return pi * radio * radio

def calcula_circunferencia_circulo(diametro):
   return pi * diametro
```

Como ves las funciones quedan super simples. Se limitan a aplicar la fórmula y retornar el resultado. No imprimen nada.

Desde el programa principal se usarían por ejemplo así:

```
import modulocirculo

print("****si no coloca una figura valida, solamente precione enter despues del: desea calcular otra figura?****")
figura_deseada=input("escriba la figura que desea calcular: ") 
if figura_deseada.lower()=="circulo":
    print("usted escogio el circulo")
    print("para calcular el area del circulo unicamente digite el radio")
    print("y para calcular la circunferencia solo digite el diametro")

    radio = float(input("escriba el radio del circulo: "))
    diametro = float(input("escriba el diametro del circulo: "))

    resultado_area_circulo = modulocirculo.calculo_area_circulo(radio)
    print("el area del circulo es: ", resultado_area_circulo)

    resultado_circunferencia_circulo = modulocirculo.calculo_circunferencia_circulo(diametro)
    print("la circunferencia del circulo es: ", resultado_circunferencia_circulo)
```

### Y si por lo que sea...

...necesitas retornar dos resultados, Python también te lo permite si los separas por comas en el `return`. Por ejemplo:

```
from math import pi

def calculo_area_y_circunferencia(radio):
   diametro = radio*2
   area = pi * radio * radio
   circunf = pi * diametro
   return area, circunf
```

Y podrías usarlo así (observa cómo recojo los dos resultados en dos variables, separadas por coma):

```
r = float(input("Radio? "))
area, circunferencia = calculo_area_y_circunferencia(r)
print("Area=", area)
print("Circunferencia=", circunferencia)
```

Comment: pffff gracias por la ayuda y todo pero.... apenas estoy empezando, aun no se mucho y lo que estoy intentando hacer lo hago con lo poco que eh aprendido en clases, y no entendí muchas de las cosas que pusiste por que no se que son, aun  no se casi nada.  Pero gracias por la ayuda